# Unable to Set RTFBody Property of Outlook.TaskItem

Tags: vb.net, outlook, arrays, richtext, primary-interop-assembly

I'm trying to set the RTFBody property of a TaskItem (using the Office PIAs).  Below is a snippet of what I'm trying to do and it's throwing an exception.  Has anyone tried to set the RTFBody before and if so, how are you doing it?

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
Dim t As Outlook.TaskItem = DirectCast(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem), Outlook.TaskItem)
t.Status = Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskNotStarted
t.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal
t.Subject = "test subject"
t.RTFBody = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}}{\*\generator Riched20 15.0.4599}{\*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\f0\fs22 Test Body: First Line\parSecond Line of Text\par}")
```

I can retrieve the RTFBody property when debugging, but cannot set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting `RTFBody`, simply setting the `Body` property to the (ANSI encoded) RTF byte array has the desired effect, cf. also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786544/5085211).